# How to Add Export button in Jquery Custom Datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, datatable

I am using a Web Template for my web site. I am developing with ASP.NET webform. The data will be shown in a Gridview. The Template also has a custom datatable file but without an Export button. I am sharing the js file here. Can anyone help me to edit the jquery and add the export button (PDF, Excel, and Copy)!
Thanks

```
(function($) {
'use strict';

$.HSCore.components.HSDatatables = {
    /**
    *
    *
    * @var Object _baseConfig
    */
    _baseConfig: {
        paging: true
    },

    /**
    *
    *
    * @var jQuery pageCollection
    */
    pageCollection: $(),

    /**
    * Initialization of Datatables wrapper.
    *
    * @param String selector (optional)
    * @param Object config (optional)
    *
    * @return jQuery pageCollection - collection of initialized items.
    */

    init: function(selector, config) {
        this.collection = selector && $(selector).length ? $(selector) : $();
        if (!$(selector).length) return;

        this.config = config && $.isPlainObject(config) ?
        $.extend({}, this._baseConfig, config) : this._baseConfig;

        this.config.itemSelector = selector;

        this.initDatatables();

        return this.pageCollection;
    },

    initDatatables: function() {
        //Variables
        var $self = this,
            config = $self.config,
            collection = $self.pageCollection;

        //Actions
        this.collection.each(function(i, el) {
            //Variables
            var $this = $(el),
            $info = $this.data('dt-info'),
            $search = $this.data('dt-search'),
            $entries = $this.data('dt-entries'),
            $pagination = $this.data('dt-pagination'),
            $detailsInvoker = $this.data('dt-details-invoker'),

            pageLength = $this.data('dt-page-length'),
            isResponsive = Boolean($this.data('dt-is-responsive')),
            isSelectable = Boolean($this.data('dt-is-selectable')),
            isColumnsSearch = Boolean($this.data('dt-is-columns-search')),
            isColumnsSearchTheadAfter = Boolean($this.data('dt-is-columns-search-thead-after')),
            isShowPaging = Boolean($this.data('dt-is-show-paging')),
            scrollHeight = $this.data('dt-scroll-height'),

            paginationClasses = $this.data('dt-pagination-classes'),
            paginationItemsClasses = $this.data('dt-pagination-items-classes'),
            paginationLinksClasses = $this.data('dt-pagination-links-classes'),
            paginationNextClasses = $this.data('dt-pagination-next-classes'),
            paginationNextLinkClasses = $this.data('dt-pagination-next-link-classes'),
            paginationNextLinkMarkup = $this.data('dt-pagination-next-link-markup'),
            paginationPrevClasses = $this.data('dt-pagination-prev-classes'),
            paginationPrevLinkClasses = $this.data('dt-pagination-prev-link-classes'),
            paginationPrevLinkMarkup = $this.data('dt-pagination-prev-link-markup'),

            table = $this.DataTable({
                pageLength: pageLength,
                responsive: isResponsive,
                scrollY: scrollHeight ? scrollHeight : '',
                scrollCollapse: scrollHeight ? true : false,
                paging: isShowPaging ? isShowPaging : config.paging,
                drawCallback: function( settings ) {
                    var api = this.api(),
                        info = api.page.info();

                    $($info).html(
                        'Showing ' + (info.start + 1) + ' to ' + info.end + ' of ' + info.recordsTotal + ' Entries'
                    );
            }
            }),

            info = table.page.info(),
            paginationMarkup = '';

            if (scrollHeight) {
                $(table.context[0].nScrollBody).mCustomScrollbar({
                    scrollbarPosition: 'outside'
                });
            }

            $($search).on('keyup', function() {
                table.search(this.value).draw();
            });

            if(isColumnsSearch == true) {
                table.columns().every(function () {
                    var that = this;

                    if(isColumnsSearchTheadAfter == true) {
                        $('.dataTables_scrollFoot').insertAfter('.dataTables_scrollHead');
                    }

                    $('input', this.footer()).on('keyup change', function () {
                        if (that.search() !== this.value) {
                            that
                            .search(this.value)
                            .draw();
                        }
                    });

                    $('select', this.footer()).on('change', function () {
                        if (that.search() !== this.value) {
                            that
                            .search(this.value)
                            .draw();
                        }
                    });
                });
            }

            $($entries).on('change', function() {
                var val = $(this).val();

                table.page.len(val).draw();

                // Pagination
                if (isShowPaging == true) {
                    $self.pagination($pagination, table, paginationClasses, paginationItemsClasses, paginationLinksClasses, paginationNextClasses, paginationNextLinkClasses, paginationNextLinkMarkup, paginationPrevClasses, paginationPrevLinkClasses, paginationPrevLinkMarkup, val);
                }
            });

            if(isSelectable == true) {
                $($this).on('change', 'input', function() {
                    $(this).parents('tr').toggleClass('checked');
                })
            }

            // Pagination
            if (isShowPaging == true) {
                $self.pagination($pagination, table, paginationClasses, paginationItemsClasses, paginationLinksClasses, paginationNextClasses, paginationNextLinkClasses, paginationNextLinkMarkup, paginationPrevClasses, paginationPrevLinkClasses, paginationPrevLinkMarkup, info.pages);
            }

            // Details
            $self.details($this, $detailsInvoker, table);

            //Actions
            collection = collection.add($this);
        });
    },

    pagination: function(target, table, pagiclasses, pagiitemclasses, pagilinksclasses, paginextclasses, paginextlinkclasses, paginextlinkmarkup, pagiprevclasses, pagiprevlinkclasses, pagiprevlinkmarkup, pages) {
        var info = table.page.info(),
        paginationMarkup = '';

        for (var i = 0; i < info.recordsTotal; i++) {
            if (i % info.length == 0) {
                paginationMarkup += i / info.length == 0 ? '<li class="' + pagiitemclasses + '"><a id="datatablePaginationPage' + (i / info.length) + '" class="' + pagilinksclasses + ' active" href="#!" data-dt-page-to="' + (i / info.length) + '">' + ((i / info.length) + 1) + '</a></li>' : '<li class="' + pagiitemclasses + '"><a id="' + target + (i / info.length) + '" class="' + pagilinksclasses + '" href="#!" data-dt-page-to="' + (i / info.length) + '">' + ((i / info.length) + 1) + '</a></li>';
            }
        }

        $('#' + target).html(
            '<ul class="' + pagiclasses + '">\
            <li class="' + pagiprevclasses + '">\
            <a id="' + target + 'Prev" class="' + pagiprevlinkclasses + '" href="#!" aria-label="Previous">' + pagiprevlinkmarkup + '</a>\
            </li>' +
            paginationMarkup +
            '<li class="' + paginextclasses + '">\
            <a id="' + target + 'Next" class="' + paginextlinkclasses + '" href="#!" aria-label="Next">' + paginextlinkmarkup + '</a>\
            </li>\
            </ul>'
        );

        $('#' + target + ' [data-dt-page-to]').on('click', function() {
            var $page = $(this).data('dt-page-to'),
                info = table.page.info();

            $('#' + target + ' [data-dt-page-to]').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
            table.page($page).draw('page');
        });

        $('#' + target + 'Next').on('click', function() {
            var $currentPage = $('#' + target + ' [data-dt-page-to].active');

            table.page('next').draw('page');

            if ($currentPage.parent().next().find('[data-dt-page-to]').length) {
                $('#' + target + ' [data-dt-page-to]').removeClass('active');
                $currentPage.parent().next().find('[data-dt-page-to]').addClass('active');
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        });

        $('#' + target + 'Prev').on('click', function() {
            var $currentPage = $('#' + target + ' [data-dt-page-to].active');

            table.page('previous').draw('page');

            if ($currentPage.parent().prev().find('[data-dt-page-to]').length) {
                $('#' + target + ' [data-dt-page-to]').removeClass('active');
                $currentPage.parent().prev().find('[data-dt-page-to]').addClass('active');
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        });
    },

    format: function(value) {
        return value;
    },

    details: function(el, invoker, table) {
        if (!invoker) return;

        //Variables
        var $self = this;

        $(el).on('click', invoker, function() {
            var tr = $(this).closest('tr'),
            row = table.row(tr);

            if (row.child.isShown()) {
                row.child.hide();
                tr.removeClass('opened');
            } else {
                row.child($self.format(tr.data('details'))).show();
                tr.addClass('opened');
            }
        });
    }
};
 })(jQuery);
```

Comment: Have you looked at examples, such as [this one](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/simple.html)? Note that you will need the `dom` option `dom: 'Bfrtip'` using `B` for "buttons". And you will need to download the required Buttons libraries - I recommend the [download builder](https://datatables.net/download/) for that. Or just copy the relevant libraries referred to in the example. If that does not help, maybe you can clarify the problem?

Comment: Actually, I have to use the Template Datatable. If I want to use Traditional Datatable then the export button works but no my CSS. So I want to add an Export button to my Template Datatable. I am not good at javascript. So I need help to edit it. Thanks

Comment: In your JavaScript you already have a DataTable definition `table = $this.DataTable({...})` and it already contains various initialization options (e.g. `pageLength: pageLength`). So, I think you are saying that you cannot add the buttons section directly in there - is that correct? (I think I may have misunderstood the question, sorry for that.)

Comment: Yes. Right. Here I am unable to add the Export button in this js. I need help to add the Export button here. Thanks